# How do I replicate a vector_float3 in Swift from Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit

I am trying to translate this code from Objective-C into Swift, but I am having a hard time figuring out what `vector_mix` does in this context. I see that `vector_mix` is available in Swift but the `vector_float3` type is not available.

```
SCNNode *car = [_vehicleNode presentationNode];
SCNVector3 carPos = car.position; //this is a SCNVector3
vector_float3 targetPos = {carPos.x, 30., carPos.z + 25.};
vector_float3 cameraPos = SCNVector3ToFloat3(_cameraNode.position);
cameraPos = vector_mix(cameraPos, targetPos, (vector_float3)(cameraDamping));
_cameraNode.position = SCNVector3FromFloat3(cameraPos);
```

It seems like it is taking the x from the `cameraPos` the y from the `targetPos` and making up a z from the `cameraDamping`, but then why would you even bother writing the `targetPos` `x`, `y` and `z`?

I know from [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swift-language/slwe62yKsWo) that the `vector_float3` is not available in Swift right now, but there has to be a way to simulate something similar to it. I just don't understand what the heck it is in this context.

How do I replicate a vector_float3 in Swift? Or how do I write this code in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** SIMD types are now available in Swift

---

you can just use SCNVector3 everywhere and reimplement the missing utils (such as the mix function)

```
SCNNode *car = [_vehicleNode presentationNode];
SCNVector3 carPos = car.position;
SCNVector3 targetPos = SCNVector3Make(carPos.x, 30., carPos.z + 25.);
SCNVector3 cameraPos = _cameraNode.position;
cameraPos = SCNVector3Make(cameraPos.x * (1.0 - cameraDamping) + targetPos.x * cameraDamping,
                           cameraPos.y * (1.0 - cameraDamping) + targetPos.y * cameraDamping,
                           cameraPos.z * (1.0 - cameraDamping) + targetPos.z * cameraDamping);
_cameraNode.position = cameraPos;
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? The mix function is available.